# I cant upgrade pyOpenSSL on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, salt-stack, pyopenssl

Im working within the **`SaltStack`** system on a ubuntu box and Im trying to figure out how to upgrade **`pyOpenSSL`** to above 0.14 as requested by the system.  However, i cant find any way to do that.  anyone can shed some light on how this is done I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade PyOpenSSL
```